# Javascript: show/hide div on linked page

Tags: javascript

I am displaying data from one page in another page in the following way:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){  
        $( "#2017" ).load( "data.html .2017" );
        $( "#2016" ).load( "data.html .2016" );
    });
</script>   

    <div id="2017"></div>
    <div id="2016"></div>
```

...BUT I also need to be able to hide (onload) certain div classes from within the linked file...

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.private-files').hide();
    }); 
</script>
```

I know that the code below will hide divs by class if they are contained in the main page, but how can I make it so that divs in the page to which I am linking will also be hidden?

Comment: You could write some CSS to hide the given divs, or use a callback to execute the hide() function after the page has loaded.

Comment: I thought of doing it that way, but isn't this possible with only JS?

Comment: CSS is applied to any DOM changes so you are not required to use JS.

Answer (score 3):

Simply hide after the subpage has loaded:

```
 $( "#2017" ).load( "data.html", function(){
   $('.private-files').hide();
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. The code you gave would be limited to div classes contained within given div ids (in this case, '2017'). I need to have it so div classes anywhere in the page are hidden, and not necessarily only those inside a given div id...

Comment: @PaulClift did you try this snippet before dismissing it? It's a new query. It will apply to the entire document.

Comment: @Our_Benefactors I did try it, but it only hid divs inside the parent '2017' id ...... what am I not getting here?

Comment: Maybe I didn't express myself very clearly. What I need is for all divs of class 'private-files' inside 'data.html' to be hidden when that page is loaded from the main page.